# iframe refusing to be responsive inside container div

Tags: css, iframe, responsive-design, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I'm trying to make `iframe` responsive inside `div`, there are plenty of resources on the web on how to do this, but the common solution is not working for my case for YouTube video embeds.

I'm using Skeleton CSS Boilerplate. I have a nested `div` structure like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row item">
        <div class="six columns">
            <iframe> </iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="six columns">
            <iframe> </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `iframe` were protruding outside the right edge of the containing `div` (class `.six.columns`) so I tried the following two `css` strategies (below).

However, with each of these strategies, `<iframe>` have become huge, and seem to have taken on the width of the `.container` `div` (or perhaps the `.row` `div`), instead of the immediate parent, the `.six.columns` `div`.

```
div > iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and

```
div.six.columns iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I just want the `<iframe>` to responsively fit inside the `.six.columns` `div`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you add `div.six.columns{position:relative;}`?

Comment: @Pangloss Fantastic, that worked! But now the videos are squeezed in height. How do I make the the height of the container `div` adjust please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the container to `position:relative` in order to have the `absolute` to work.

To maintain the video aspect ratio, wrap the `iframe` into another `div`, and use the `padding` trick. Let's say the video is `16:9`, the `padding-bottom` value would be `9/16=56.25%`. Simple demo follows.

https://jsfiddle.net/dfkhkLhp/

```css
.youtube {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
.youtube iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="youtube">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HkMNOlYcpHg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```